# Google Wallet API and PHP, Handling Postbacks

Tags: php, android-pay

I'm trying to handle `postbacks` with `Google Wallet` but I'm unsure as to the best way to detect the type of `postback`.

For example, how would I differentiate a `Subscription Cancellation` vs a `Subscription Sale` vs a `One Time Purchase`?

I've read the Documentation: https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback

It's a little unclear as to the best method, as you only provide a single `postback` URL for everything.

```
if($decoded_jwt->typ === "google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1/canceled") {
   //Logic to handle cancel
}
```

Would this work in production? What would I use if it weren't a cancellation?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A single purchase `typ` : `google/payments/inapp/item/v1/postback/buy`
- A subscription purchase `typ` : `google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1/postback/buy`
- A subscription cancellation `typ`: `google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1/canceled`

I'm going through some of my old notes, and remember that the [docs for subscription postback](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#5) seem to have an error - which is probably why you asked :)

I ran into exceptions back then and after debugging, the `typ` for the subscription postback is actually what I have above (re: the docs show the postback typ for single item).

Hth....

---

### Update

> When the cancellation postback is sent, do I get the sellerdata in the JWT?

Nope. You'll see a sample [cancellation postback JWT in the docs](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6)

> How would I know which account to deactivate in the event of a cancellation? Or should I store the orderID?

You will get the *original* `orderId` in the cancellation postback. So yes, you'll need to store it.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find this anywhere. The docs don't seem complete when it come to this. At least not for PHP.

Comment: How would I tell if the payment went through on a subscription then? Would I use the same postback URL?

Comment: @Guy Well, you only get 1 postback url in your account so yes, it's the same url for all. You'd need to parse the `typ` in the postback to "know" what it is (and handle appropriately)...you can also go deeper if you need to and check for the existence (or non-existence) of fields (e.g. a subscription postback will have `recurrence`, single item will not)

Comment: A postback call would be made on payment then?

Comment: @Guy Yup - if Google successfully charges, otherwise, no (payment) postback. Cancellation postback is when a user cancels a subscription or if Google can't charge a subscription payment for some reason (e.g. before subscription ends, card fails). Hth....

Comment: When the cancellation postback is sent, do I get the sellerdata in the JWT? How would I know which account to deactivate in the event of a cancellation? Or should I store the orderID?